# Does wordpress export work as a backup for entire site?

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, if i say export all content of the website. When I import it, am I getting the same site back or what? No one seems to suggest that it's a viable way of backing up your site. I do not have another server to test it out, and I do not want to break the current site without a backup

Comment: you can backup databse and files manually or using plugins like duplicater.export import works but sometimes you have to re configure menus and some other things

Answer (score 1):

No WordPress export doesn't take the full backup of site, for the backup you will need to use the plugins Like

Backwpup

Updraft plus

Answer (score 0):

it's taking pages and posts backup, u need to keep a backup of your wp-content folder too (for images, themes, plugins).

Best way of taking backup is zipping the whole folder and a copy of sql.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this.. there are two ways:
1) use a plugin for backup 
2) without using the plugin

https://skillcrush.com/2015/04/23/backing-up-wordpress/